# How to fix google apps script memory problem?

Tags: google-apps-script, out-of-memory

So I created an infinite loop by accident today in Google Apps Script and I think it broke my script, because everything I run after it just throws out of memory error. Is there any way I can fix it or do I just have to wait 24 hours?

```
var carSheet = ss.getSheetByName(CAR_FORM);
var carData = carSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var lastRow = carSheet.getLastRow() - 1;

for(var i = 0; i < carData; i++) {
   //Do something here
}
```

Comment: If the script is still running in the background - go from the script editor on `View-> Executions` and stop the execution manually.

Comment: The script is not running anymore since I cannot terminate anything under Executions, however I am still getting out of memory error when I tried to do anything.